# Immutable names in /dev/disk

Tags: linux, usb, partition, disk

There are four entries in /dev/disk which I am interested in.

1. by-id
2. by-label
3. by-path
4. by-uuid

Which of the entries contain immutable names for physical drives? By immutable, I mean that the name shouldn't change if I

1. change the usb/pci port used to connect to the drive.
2. destroy and create partitions (GPT).
3. move from one computer to another (external hard-drive).

For example, /dev/sda can change to /dev/sdb if a different flash drive is connected. But the UUID stays the same. I don't mind if a partition's path changes (I think the UUID changes if you destroy and then recreate a partition), but the complete physical drive must stay at the same location (/dev/sdX may change, but the UUID doesn't when the usb port is changed).

Please suggest relevant tags.

**Edit** -
Can you say the same for partlabel and partuuid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: you can use `by-label` or `by-uuid` to keep names immutable.

In detail:
Disk names (`/dev/sdX`) are given by `kernel` based on `controller` priority (master/slave) disk attached to. If you are moving disk from one USB port to another, for `kernel` it is like switching a controller. This is why names are changed from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb`.
The directory `/dev/disk` is related to `filesystem` located on the disk. `Label` and `uuid` are `filesystem` attributes which are given on `filesystem` creation and can be changed after.
They are immutable and can survive:

- disk migration from one computer to another.
- disk migration from one controller to another on same computer.

However `by-label` and `by-uuid` **will not survive** if you destroy the `partition`, but the same `label`, `uuid` names can be given upon `filesystem` creation. So newly created `filesystem` will be mounted at same `mount point`.
I personally prefer to use `by-label` as it supported by many `filesystems`, short and descriptive.

More information about [persistent block device naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming#by-label).